# MVC - Query string and action parameter issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action method with the following signature,

```
ActionResult Search(string searchQuery)
```

This gets called from a partial view on button submit from a form. Problem is, please look at the 2 patterns below. When I submit my search key from my page it uses the following url (suppose search key is tool)

```
Search/?searchQuery=tool
```

But then if I click on a tool then,

```
Search/tool?searchQuery=garden
```

Now my method is reading tool in the parameter instead of garden (which is expected of course). I presume this is to do with incorrect presentation of items from both the context of the item itself and that of search.

Is there a nice way of resolving this issue? I want to read the query string term and search for it from the main search context i.e. `Search/?searchQuery=<term>`   no matter where I am.

Comment: Can you show your `ActionLink` or `Form` code from views?

Comment: show your code, how you are reading the query string?

Comment: It should not read tool into searchQuery for either of those, unless you have a routing problem, but we would need to see your routing table for that.

Comment: It was routing problem as you stated Robert. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

To get the `QueryString`, in your controller you should write something like this:

`var mystring =Request.QueryString["searchQuery"];`

This will get the `query string` no matter where is placed in your `url`.

Answer (score 1):

Rename the input to

```
ActionResult Search(string searchQuery)
```

The model binder will then deserialize the query string param to that input value. It will work for both route params and query string params.

Comment: Sorry question edited. I just typed it so typed it wrong. It is searchQuery